# Writing complex MySQL Join query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

This may be simple for some, but I cannot work it out.

I have 3 tables:

Teams, Users, Tags

```
Teams                 Users                Tags
-------------------   ------------------   -----------------------
userID | teamUserID   userID  | username   userID  | name  | value
-------------------   ------------------   -----------------------
1      | 2            1       | dan        2       | myTag | 1
1      | 3            2       | bob        2       | aTag  | 2
1      | 4            3       | jon        3       | bTag  | 1
                      4       | rob        4       | cTag  | 5
```

Each team can have a number of users in it, and each user can own a number of tags.

I need a query which will provide a list of users in any given team, with a total number of tags they have.

So when I request results from team 1 (dan's team) it should return this:

```
-----------------------------------
userID  | username  | tagTotalValue
-----------------------------------
2       | bob       | 3
3       | jon       | 1
4       | rob       | 5
```

I have this query so far, but it just gives me one record with an overall total for the whole team, rather than a list of all the users in the team separately with their totals.

```
SELECT username, SUM(value) tagTotalValue
FROM users u LEFT JOIN tags t
ON u.userID = t.userID
WHERE u.userID IN (SELECT teamUserID FROM teams WHERE userID = 1)
```

Help!

If anyone can explain a good way of working out how to build these queries, I would be very grateful to learn. Do I just need to do a mySQL course, or is there a simple method I can employ?

Comment: Your data model makes no sense.  Why does `teams` have two user ids?

Comment: userID is the owner of the team, and teamUserID are the member userIDs. I appreciate the naming might be a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a query which will provide a list of users in any given team,
>   with a total number of tags they have.

This seems to have little to do with the query you have written.  You should start by joining the three tables together and then aggregating.  The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT t.teamId, u.userId, u.username, count(ta.userId) as numTags
FROM teams t JOIN
     users u 
     ON t.teamUserID = u.UserId LEFT JOIN
     tags ta
     ON u.userID = ta.userID
WHERE t.teamId = @teamId  -- this can be removed
GROUP BY t.teamId, u.userId, u.username;
```

This query makes the leap that `teams` has a column that identifies the team -- say `teamId`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I really appreciate your advice. with a few tweaks, this works perfectly.